# CSS animations in HTML inline

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I would like to add CSS animations inline in HTML. The reason is simple, I am trying to design an email signature that includes some animations. It seems that I am not allowed to add the `<head></head>` section. So, I am stuck. How can I either (a) reference CSS inline (HTML) that include animations, or (b) how can I call an external CSS stylesheet without using the `<head></head>` tag? Thanks!

`.logos {transition: .1s ease-in-out;}`
`.logos:hover {transform: scale(1.2);}`
`.logos:active {transform: scale(.8);}`

Comment: hover animation on email signature?

Comment: Not possible with **inline** styling.

Comment: Just put the <style> tags inside the body if you have access to that. It will work more or less the same way. As Paulie said, there's no way to do this with *inline* styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible (thank you for commenting @Pauline_D and @ZachSaucier)